# @Autowired on the method, is the method executed at runtime random?

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I initialized and found that the method execution was random.
But I don't know why this is happening?

The code is shown below, the order of output is sometimes different

```
@Autowired
public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test():1");
}
@Autowired
public void test2( MyUserDetialsService userService) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test2( MyUserDetialsService userService):5");
}
@Autowired
public void a( MyUserDetialsService userService) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("a( MyUserDetialsService userService):2");
}
@Autowired
public void a() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("a():3");
}
```

Comment: A code snippet would be appreciated rather than a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Order of execution is in alphabetical order. You can see it by changing the name of the function from test to ztest and you will see the output will change.

Also I tested more and found out that sometime its not alphabetical. It depends to parameter numbers too. but without parameters it is alphabetical. you can see my example here https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/autowired-which-function-works-first